# Conditional Reference

Tags: c#-3.0, .net-3.0

I have an application that I was writing that communicates with a third-party application via a `Component Object Model` library.  I must reference this COM library within the Visual Studio project itself in order for the application I am writing to work.  There is also a .NET wrapper library that I must reference in the Visual Studio project in order to communicate with the COM library.

Is there a way to to create a **conditional initialization** of a class, in order to use a method within a .NET class within the .NET wrapper library, that will work in a later version of the third-party COM library itself.

The problem I ran into was that I was trying to reference a feature of the COM library that only existed in a later version.  The version of the wrapper itself was identical because it was backwards compatible.  When I attempted to access this new feature the program I was writing would silently close when I started it when the previous version of the third-party application was installed.

Is there a way I could have avoided this behavior without changing how the way the application itself was built?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure whether I understand term "reference a class".

You can do a conditional referencing of an entire Assembly (DLL)

```
<Reference 
        Include="LegacyServices.dll" 
        Condition="$(AppVersion == '2.0')" />
```

or conditionally include a source file into a project

```
<Compile 
       Include="LegacyServices.cs" 
       Condition="$(AppVersion == '2.0')" />
```

Both using [MSBuild Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) in csproj file.

Comment: The thing you posted doesn't work. It says condition evaluated to '' instead of bool. Even msdn page you are refering to says it has to be `$(AppVersion) == '2.0'`. Also such references confuse visual studio (references appears even when condition is false), meanwhile [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6523223/800613) works fine with visual studio.

Comment: Could you try  Condition=" '$(AppVersion)' == '2.0'"

Comment: That would work too, but I don't know how visual studio will treat that and I don't care because `<Choose><When>` worked fine and it's much better for multiple conditional references I have.