# Automating C# Builds - how to change references to release version?

Tags: c#, build, tfs

I am trying to automate our build process.  We have a TFS structure that looks like this:

Branches/ProjectName/Version2.0/all_the_files
Branches/AnotherProjectName/Version5.0/all_the_files

$/ProjectName/working_line
$/AnotherProjectName/working_line

I have managed to use the TFS API to automatically branch from the working line to a specific release folder for each project.  The issue now is automatically building this.  I can probably figure out how to generate a build sequence, and pass in the specific location of each set of build files, but the the references won't work for two reasons:
1) The working_line directory structure is different from that of the branched code
2) in the working_line we are including references by going directly to the debug folder location of the included reference, whereas on production we would want to point to the release folder

Am I thinking about this in the wrong way, or is there some easy way to do what I'm thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try conditional reference. I am not sure is this will work for you. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523008/visual-studio-2010-conditional-references) .