# How to define preprocessor ifdef in .dll for Unity?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, c-preprocessor

I have a `.dll` (unmanaged code) that I use in Unity. I need to add some functional in my `.dll` in order to build Unity project for Android devices.

So, I need to use preprocessor functionality such as `if` in my case

I tried to add it just for test in my `.cpp` file

```
DecoderStream::DecoderStream()
{
    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "DecoderStream");  // 1 comment

#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "UNITY_ANDROID"); // 2 comment
#elif UNITY_EDITOR
    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "UNITY_EDITOR"); // 3 comment
    m_p_tex_decoder = new DecoderTextureFFmpeg();
#else
    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "else"); // 4 comment
#endif
    
}
```

If I compile this code and run it in Unity I see `1 comment` and `4 comment` I see that preprocessor conditions doesn't work, I mean it doesn't recognize that whether it android or unity editor...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you rebuilt in the different environments (whcih you expect to set/unset the switches) and use the resulting dll accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor_directives_and_macros) and as the name already suggests

> Pre-processors are a way of making text processing with your C program **before they are actually compiled**.

So if you don't compile your DLL already defining the according directives your code will basically simply result in compiling

```
DecoderStream::DecoderStream()
{
    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "DecoderStream");  // 1 comment

    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "else"); // 4 comment 
}
```

using the directives it "knows" at compile-time. And since a DLL is then already compiled to machine code it doesn't "know" the concept of pre-processors anymore.

So long story short: You'll have to use the pre-processors on Unity side and just implement different methods like

```
DecoderStream::DecoderStreamAndroid()
{
    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "DecoderStream");  // 1 comment

    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "UNITY_ANDROID"); // 2 comment
}

DecoderStream::DecoderStreamEditor()
{
    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "DecoderStream");  // 1 comment

    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "UNITY_EDITOR"); // 3 comment
    m_p_tex_decoder = new DecoderTextureFFmpeg();
}

DecoderStream::DecoderStreamElse()
{
    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "DecoderStream");  // 1 comment

    debug_in_unity("DecoderStream", "else"); // 4 comment
}
```

and call them accordingly on Unity side

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    DecoderStreamAndroid();
#elif UNITY_EDITOR
    DecoderStreamEditor();
#else
    DecoderStreamElse();
#endif
```

---

An alternative from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634744/conditional-compilation-in-referenced-assemblies) might be the [`[Conditional]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute) attribute. However, it can not be used for returning a value, only for `void` methods.