# Travis Unit tests failing: Reference 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework' not resolved

Tags: unit-testing, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up Travis CI tests for my repository here: https://github.com/douglasg14b/CSVSerializer

The tests pass locally, but with Travis CI I get the following warning and error:

> /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning :
>   Reference 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework' not
>   resolved
>
> CSVSerializerTests.cs(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   `VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace`Microsoft'. Are you
>   missing an assembly reference?

How can I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423489/problems-with-travis-for-c-sharp), it seems like the referenced package Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework only is available with Visual Studio installed. And that isn't possible when running tests on Travis' build systems, which are running Linux.

A simple solution to this problem is to use Nunit, a test framework that also works with Mono, the Linux implementation of .NET.
To use it, simply implement a Shim class that covers the functionality of your tests, remove the original reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework from the project's references, and you are good to go.

Here's what to do:

1. Install the following packages in Visual Studio Using NuGET package manager:

   - Nunit Test Adapter
   - Nunit
   - nunit.framework
2. To get rid of the dependency to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework add [this shim class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31739491/5166812) to your test project.
3. Removed the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework in your test project.
4. Run the tests
5. Commit your project and see it run in Travis CI